# Impossible to manage sticky dough

Tags: baking, bread, sourdough

Even after finding many people with my same problem and some nice answers, nothing really works. I have watched many youtube tutorials on how to handle and shape sticky dough but believe me, I have never seen something as sticky as what I'm dealing with right here.

My dough will stick to absolutely everything, even the brand new dough scraper that I bought is useless against this. I have tried everything: oil, flour, cold water, a spatula, a scraper... NOTHING works.

I'm doing just as many youtube videos and tutorials suggest and they never end up with such an sticky monster as I do. It's driving me crazy.

I really appreciate your help,

This is a short clip of me tryng to fold my dough: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h12qkh14uyrd0ev/video-1468336333.mp4?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: Add more flour to your dough when you mix it so it's not so wet?

Comment: What kind of dough is it? Can you link to the recipe?

Comment: It looked like the scraper was doing a pretty good job.  (It's one of my favorite kitchen tools, by the way.)  Is this a yeast bread recipe?  If you can provide some more information, that will help us figure out if there's something wrong with the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your link does not seem to be working for me right now, but assuming you are making a leavened bread dough, here's some tips. Let me know if you've tried all these before.

1. Wet your hands before handling the dough. This will temporarily keep the dough from sticking to your hands but be warned: this effect will not last forever. Make sure to keep wetting your hands as you go.
2. If you're getting near baking time, go ahead and flour the surface and your hands. Ge generous with the flour, too little will find yourself elbow-deep in dough with no way out
3. With the scraper, wet the scraper a bit before using it to reduce "drag" on the dough.

If you could provide more details on the exact makeup of the dough, that could provide more insight, but that's all I have for you right now.